# Is there a way to conditionally reference a function such as .replace() on a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Staying in the var statement only, for example:

```
var foo = 0, bar = "abc".replace("a", "x"); // want bar to equal "abc"
var foo = 1, bar = "abc".replace("a", "x"); // want bar to equal "xbc"
```

Only do the replace if foo is 1.  Something like:

```
var foo = 0, bar = "abc"[foo ? "replace" : "some noOp function"]("a", "x");
```

Instead of "replace" is there a noOp type function that could be used for "some noOp function"?  I do not want to modify any prototypes.  Is there a way to do this using existing methods?

"abc" can be in a variable, such as:

```
var baz = "abc", foo = 0, bar = baz[foo ? "replace" : "some noOp function"]("a", "x")
```

Comment: What would you expect `bar` to equal if `foo` was `0`?

Comment: @Bryan Downing "abc"

Comment: Readability over brevity.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `var bar = foo ? "abc".replace("a", "x") : "abc"`?

Comment: @axiac  Wanted a way to replace the function name.  See accepted answer.  Your suggestion obviously works, but it's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a string, you can use `toString/valueOf` method, which will return the same string, and it doesn't take arguments, so you can pass whatever you want without worrying.

```js
function bar(foo) {
  return "abc"[foo ? "replace" : "toString"]("a", "x");
}

console.log(bar(true));
console.log(bar(false));
```

Anyhow, I don't recommend doing this. It's better to not call the function, and I don't find it very clean.

Comment: Perfect.  This works.  Thank you.  Will mark as the answer.  Agree with your comment, but there are always situations where....      :  )

Comment: Yeah I know, but felt the need to add the comment, for future readers :P. And you can also use `valueOf`.